# Why multiindex dataframe will return all index after selection?

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I find one thing is very strange about multiindex dataframe:

For a very simple df:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([{'Name': 'Chris', 'Item Purchased': 'Sponge', 'Cost': 22.50},

{'Name': 'Kevyn', 'Item Purchased': 'Kitty Litter', 'Cost': 2.50},

{'Name': 'Filip', 'Item Purchased': 'Spoon', 'Cost': 5.00}],

index=['Store 1', 'Store 2', 'Store 3'])

df3 = df.reset_index()

df3 = df3.set_index(['index', 'Name'])
```

If I want to get index only the cost larger than 4 dollar. It's easy to select:

```
df4 = df3[df3['Cost'] > 4]
df4
```

[image]

But when I try to get store id from index :

```
df4.index.levels[0]
```

It should be only Store 1 and Store 3, but the actual result:

```
Index(['Store 1', 'Store 2', 'Store 3'], dtype='object', name='index')
```

So, it seems index will still return all member from the original index, even after selection.

Could someone please help me why this happens and how could I get correct index after selection?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`MultiIndex.remove_unused_levels`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.remove_unused_levels.html):

```
df4.index = df4.index.remove_unused_levels()

print (df4.index.levels[0])
```